# How to configure tomcat into two different domains in one application?

Tags: spring, tomcat

I wanted to split my applications so that I can configure Tomkat into two different domains "example.com" and "api.example.com". Is it possible to do this with one application? So that some requests are processed on subdomain.

Comment: Which web-server are you using to redirect the traffic to your tomcat? Nginx by any chance?

Comment: Doesn't matter which one. Maybe ngnix + apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can multiple domains of redirecting to multiple Tomcat applications. You would need to install the applications in your Tomcat and make them listen for different ports. Then if you were to use Nginx, all you have to do is change the server clause in your `/sites-enabled/` directory from your installation. For your case, you will need two files, one for each domain.

**FILE 1**

```
server {
    server_name  example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

**FILE 2**

```
server {
    server_name  api.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }
}
```

You can find more information in the following [url](http://javadeveloper.asia/configuring-nginx-in-front-of-tomcat-or-other-java-application-server/).